# Recording and saving audio file without replacing another

Tags: android, audio, android-studio, record

I'm developing an android app which has a record feature. I'm able to record and save the audio file into my device's storage, however there seems a problem. When I record twice, the recorded audio replaces the first recorded one.

I want my app to do like this:

- I recorded and it has successfully recorded and saved the audio
  file into the storage;
- I recorded again and has successfully recorded and saved the audio
  file into the storage;
- There would be two recorded and saved audio files in the storage.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RecordModule extends Activity {

Button SpeakBtn, StopBtn;
private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
private String outputFile = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recordmodule);

    SpeakBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SpeakBtn);
    StopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopBtn);

    StopBtn.setEnabled(false);
    SpeakBtn.setEnabled(true);
    outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";

    myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

    SpeakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                myAudioRecorder.start();
            }

            catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SpeakBtn.setEnabled(false);
            StopBtn.setEnabled(true);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    StopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myAudioRecorder.stop();
            myAudioRecorder.release();
            myAudioRecorder = null;

            StopBtn.setEnabled(false);
            SpeakBtn.setEnabled(true);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_record_module, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I have one question about your code, did you suppose that recorded files show in your app as it runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first recording is being overwritten, so the others need to have another file name.

I would suggest you to use output file name as the time when the record was created:

```
Date createdTime = new Date();    
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + createdTime + "_rec.3gp";
```

Comment: When I try to import the date class, it gives me two choices; java.util.Date & java.sql.Date. Which one should I choose?

Comment: I tried your code in real device, and after pressing the stop record button, the app gave me an error which says: Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped. Why is that?

Comment: it's java.util.Date; and the error should be because you probably used sql

Comment: No, I used java.util.Date yet the error still occurs. Is there any other way?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot do that. The only way I could try my code is to copy&paste my .apk into my device, because the emulator doesn't work on my unit and when I try my code through the use of usb cable, my unit doesn't recognize my device. So I'm being unable to see the logcat (if that's what you're asking).

Comment: Nah thats bad, u will need to use your phone directly throught cable, its much easier and so quicker than doing this...the problem of connecting your phone may be, that your pc doesnt have the right driver for the phone, what phone do you have?

Comment: Its a local brand, and yes you're right that my unit doesn't have the right driver for my phone. I've tried installing universal driver but unlucky my unit still doesn't recognize my device when I try running my code on my device through a usb cable.

Comment: The problem seems to be coming from the part where you asked me to try changing it. When I get it back (the code above), the app runs pretty fine.

Comment: Anyway my problem has been solved. Thanks for helping and giving me an idea why I was facing the problem stated above. I used SimpleDateFormat class instead of Date class, and now its all working pretty fine.